# After Magento upgrade to 2.4.5 setup:di:compile asks for wrong elasticserach file

Tags: elasticsearch

```
root@vps-sssssss:/home/sssss/ssssssss# bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% 1 sec 119.0 MiBClass "Magento\Elasticsearch\Elasticsearch5\SearchAdapter\Mapper" not found#0 /home/sssssss/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#1 /home/ssssssss/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
```

After upgrade to Magento 2.4.5 CE `setup:di:compile` show error ... Because not showing existing products ...  As can see  - `setup:di:compile` looking for file wich is from lower Elasticsearch version (I have ES 7.17)
Anybody have ideas inthis case? Thanks!

Comment: Try with disable third party modules. then run compile cmd.

Comment: Did you check the search engine in database in core_config_data table. Its should be elasticsearch7 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the below configuration in admin

**STORES > Configuration > CATALOG > Catalog > Catalog Search > Search Engine**

[image]

Flush the Magento Cache through **SYSTEM > Cache Management**

[image]

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**